# angular module: Failed to instantiate module due to

Tags: angularjs, module

I'm running through the videos of angular js tutorial. and i'm having issue with creating a module.

the error that i get is:

```
Failed to instantiate module myalcoholist due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/nomod?p0=myal...
at Error (native)
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:6:416
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:24:186
at b (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:23:251)
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:23:494
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:38:117
at n (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:7:333)
at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:37:488)
at eb (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:41:249)
at c (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:19:463
```

my code is clean, all I have is the creation of the module.

this is the html:

```
<html ng-app="myalcoholist">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha256-MfvZlkHCEqatNoGiOXveE8FIwMzZg4W85qfrfIFBfYc= sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha256-Sk3nkD6mLTMOF0EOpNtsIry+s1CsaqQC1rVLTAy+0yc= sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="model/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

and my model/app.js includes the following code:

```
(function(){
 var app = angular.module('myalcoholist',[]);
})
```

any ideas why i get this error ? any ideas regarding the issue would be greatly appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you define the function but did not call it.
Try this

```
(function(){
 var app = angular.module('myalcoholist',[]);
})()
```